# Explaining this piece of code in a javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, slideshow

http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_self

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

    if (n > x.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }

    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = x.length
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

So in the last part specifically.

```
  x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
```

This sets whichever slide is marked as slideindex=1 to block. However what if slideindex was set to 4? How does this code set the current slide to block?

Comment: `slideIndex` is increased in `plusDivs`.

Comment: I understand that, I'm referring to when it calls x [slideindex-1] and sets it to block. that would only set slideindex 1 to block right?

Comment: Please take a look where `plusDivs` is called from. You'll see `n` can be `1` or `-1`. The code sets `slideIndex` itself, it will never get wrong values. You can find the checks: `if (n > x.length)` and `if (n < 1)` ...

Comment: Plus div adds 1 or subtracts 1 from the slideindex, but slide index can be 4 or 5, depending on how many elements are in there total. I'm confused about the aforementioned code x [slide index-1] what does this do exactly? could you break it down as much as possible? is it subtracting 1 from slide index and setting that to block? or is it setting slide index to 1? the "-" is confusing and I'm not sure what it means

Comment: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object, i.e HTMLCollection. `x[slideIndex - 1]` refers to an element in that collection. There are limits for `slideIndex` i.e. it can have values from 1 to `x.length`. `slideIndex - 1` is used as an index to correct the index value to the range of 0 - x.length - 1.

Comment: But it's static, when the slide changes due to the plusdivs, its still set to only display the 1st element in the array collection, right?

Comment: Static? How? You've just stated "Plus div adds 1 or subtracts 1 from the slideindex". It does that on every click ...

Comment: Right! But the command to set     x[slideIndex - 1] is a static 1, so it would only show 1. Thats what im confused about. To me its essentially saying "Take the 1st slideindex inside myslides and set that to block. but this isnt the case apparently.

Comment: How on earth `slideIndex - 1` can be static, if `slideIndex` gets values between 1 and `x.length`?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh, so slideIndex is getting subtracted by 1? And then that result is getting set to Block? So if slide index was set to 4, the slide that responds to 3 would be the visible one? Im sorry im being difficult i just really want to understand this and this is the last hurdle.